# Windows 10 Upgrade Failure

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 7. However, it falls over at 71% stating `c1900101-40017` with the following errors in the setuperr.log:

```
2015-10-09 10:27:05, Error [0x08085f] MIG MigHost:
CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext:
LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Windows-RasServer-MigPlugin\RasMigPlugin.dll,
LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7f.[gle=0x0000007f]
2015-10-09 10:27:05, Error [0x080863] MIG MigHost:
CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc:
LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed
hr=0x8007007f.[gle=0x0000007f] 2015-10-09 20:35:49, Error [0x08085f]
MIG MigHost:
CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext:
LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Windows-RasServer-MigPlugin\RasMigPlugin.dll,
LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7f.[gle=0x0000007f]
2015-10-09 20:35:49, Error [0x080863] MIG MigHost:
CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc:
LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed
hr=0x8007007f.[gle=0x0000007f]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-installation-error-0xc1900101-0x40017/687791df-84dd-4ab5-a8ca-841b1a2a4435

Answer (score 1):

#### Windows 10 Upgrade Error c1900101 40017

> The cause for error 0xC1900101 – 0x40017 is known to be faulty drivers.
>
> There have been reports of a USB driver causing this error.  Until a specific USB driver can be determined as a root cause, if you receive this error, we recommend you unplug all USB devices (other than your mouse and keyboard) as a troubleshooting step and try the upgrade again.  If the upgrade is then successful, you can plug the devices back in and they should function normally.
>
> We have identified a few drivers associated with the following hardware or software that could be causing this problem:
>
> - NVIDIA Video card. Check to make sure you’ve upgraded to the latest video drivers
> - Disable (preferably uninstall) your Antivirus utility before attempting the upgrade.
> - Restart a few times and try again.
> - Disable General USB Devices (example - Smart Card Reader).
> - If you are using a SCSI hard disk, make sure you have drivers available for your storage device on a thumdrive and it is connected.
>     During Windows 10 setup, click the Custom Advanced Option and use the
>     Load Driver command to load the appropriate driver for the SCSI drive.
>     If this does not work and setup still fails, consider switching to a
>     IDE based hard disk.
> - Do a clean boot and try again.
> - If you are upgrading using the .ISO file, disconnect from the Internet during setup, if you are connected by LAN (Ethernet) or
>     Wi-Fi, disable both and attempt setup again.
> - If you are updating through Windows Update, when the download reaches 100% disconnect from the Internet LAN (Ethernet) or Wi-Fi and
>     proceed with the installation.
> - If that does not work, try using the .ISO file to upgrade if possible.
> - If you are connected to a domain, switch to a local account
> - If you have any external devices attached to the machine, disconnect them (example, gaming controllers, USB keys, external hard
>     disk, printers, non-essential devices).
>
> [How to: upgrade from previous versions of Windows using Windows 10
>   ISO file](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-upgrade-from-previous-versions-of-windows/31722b30-1da9-42bb-b331-0edc4649bf43)
>
> [How to download official Windows 10 ISO files](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-download-official-windows-10-iso-files/35cde7ec-5b6f-481c-a02d-dadf465df326)
>
> **If you are installing Windows 10 using Windows Update, try the following:**
>
> 1. Press Windows Key + X on the keyboard and then select “Command Prompt (Admin)” from the menu.
> 2. Stop the BITS, Cryptographic, MSI Installer and the Windows Update Services. To do this, type the following commands at a command prompt.
>      Press the “ENTER” key after you type each command.
>
>    ```
>    net stop wuauserv
>    net stop cryptSvc
>    net stop bits
>    net stop msiserver
>    ```
> 3. Now rename the SoftwareDistribution and Catroot2 folder. You can do this by typing the following commands in the Command Prompt. Press the
>      “ENTER” key after you type each command.
>
>    ```
>    ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
>    ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
>    ```
> 4. Now, let’s restart the BITS, Cryptographic, MSI Installer and the Windows Update Services. Typethe following commands in the Command
>      Prompt for this. Press the ENTER key after you type each command.
>
>    ```
>    net start wuauserv
>    net start cryptSvc
>    net start bits
>    net start msiserver
>    ```
> 5. Type Exit in the Command Prompt to close it and then restart the computer.

Source [How to: Troubleshoot common Setup and Stop Errors during Windows 10 Installation](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-troubleshoot-common-setup-and-stop-errors/324d5a5f-d658-456c-bb82-b1201f735683)